# HTTP Post as IE6 using C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I need to do a HTTP POST using C#. It needs to do a postback the same way as an IE6 page.

From the documentation the postback should look like

```
POST /.../Upload.asp?b_customerId=[O/M1234] HTTP/1.1
Content-length: 12345
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=vxvxv
Host: www.foo.com
--vxvxv
Content-disposition: form-data; name=”File1”; filename=”noColonsSpacesOrAmpersandsInHere”
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
...
<bat:Batch ...
.......
</bat:Batch>
--vxvxv--
```

I think im having trouble with the boundary characters. I tried setting the boundary in the post data and fiddler shows something similar but I get a page back with the error "Invalid procedure call or argument". the Content-disposition is in the body rather than the header to keep it within the boundaries. Im not sure that is right. Am I setting the boundary the correct way? **Can anyone give some guidance on how to do an IE6 style HTTP POST using C# ?** Thanks

**My Code**

```
data = "--vxvxv" + Environment.NewLine + 
    "Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"File1\";" + Environment.NewLine + 
    "filename=\"provideTest.xml\"" + Environment.NewLine + 
    "Content-type: text/xml" + Environment.NewLine + 
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + Environment.NewLine + 
    data + Environment.NewLine + 
    "--vxvxv--";

var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
HttpWebRequest request;
var postData = encoding.GetBytes(data);

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=vxvxv";
request.Host = "www.foo.com";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

X509Certificate2Collection certCollect = new X509Certificate2Collection();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\a\cert.pfx", "password");

certCollect.Add(cert);
request.ClientCertificates = certCollect;

using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    writeStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length); }

WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
string output = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

LogEntry.Write("Recieved : " + output);
return output;
```

**Fiddler Output (raw)**

```
POST https://../Upload.asp?b_customerId=%5BO/M1234%5D HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=vxvxv
Host: www.foo.com
Content-Length: 5500
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--vxvxv
Content-disposition: form-data; name="File1";
filename="provideTest.xml"
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...SNIP...
</bat:Batch>
--vxvxv--
```

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is that your filename is on a new line which it shouldn't be. No idea if this will cause the error mentioned but it will probably confuse things a lot at the very least.

Comment: Pretty sure that would make it invalid.

Comment: Tried it withough the newline. Same result

Comment: you are using the same variable in `@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + Environment.NewLine + 
    data +` is this correct or its just a typo here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [blogged](http://bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html) about a way of uploading multiple files using a WebClient and the possibility to send parameters as well. Here's the relevant code:

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public UploadFile()
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

and then a method to perform the upload:

```
public byte[] UploadFiles(string address, IEnumerable<UploadFile> files, NameValueCollection values)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    boundary = "--" + boundary;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Write the values
        foreach (string name in values.Keys)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"{1}{1}", name, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values[name] + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // Write the files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}", file.Name, file.Filename, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Type: {0}{1}{1}", file.ContentType, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        var boundaryBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "--");
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBuffer, 0, boundaryBuffer.Length);
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

which could be used like so:

```
using (var stream1 = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream2 = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream3 = File.Open("test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    var files = new[] 
    {
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.txt",
            ContentType = "text/plain",
            Stream = stream1
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.xml",
            ContentType = "text/xml",
            Stream = stream2
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.pdf",
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            Stream = stream3
        }
    };

    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
        { "key3", "value3" },
    };

    byte[] result = UploadFiles("http://localhost:1234/upload", files, values);
}
```

Comment: That worked. Given you the bounty. For bonus points could you explain why yours worked and mine didnt? I notice you used "application/octet-stream" where i used text. You also dont seem to set the content length.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have two potential problems:

1) The URL that you are sending formats the b_CustomerId parameter differently than the IE6 implementation. If the site you are targeting does not expect an HTML-encoded value, this could very easily be the source of the error message.

Your request:

```
Upload.asp?b_customerId=%5BO/M1234%5D
```

The IE6 request:

```
Upload.asp?b_customerId=[O/M1234]
```

In order to fix this issue, you can create a new Url from an overload of the [Uri class constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zh9wcb3.aspx) that has been marked as obsolete, but still works correctly. This overload allows you to specify that the string has already been escaped in the second parameter.

In order to use this constructor, change this line:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

to this:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url, true));
```

2) The Content-disposition tag is not formatted the same way in your request as it is in the IE6 request.

Your request:

```
Content-disposition: form-data; name="File1";
filename="provideTest.xml"
```

IE6 request:

```
Content-disposition: form-data; name=”File1”; filename=”noColonsSpacesOrAmpersandsInHere”
```

This can be resolved by changing these two lines:

```
"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"File1\";" + Environment.NewLine + 
"filename=\"provideTest.xml\"" + Environment.NewLine +
```

to:

```
"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"File1\"; " + 
"filename=\"provideTest.xml\"" + Environment.NewLine +
```

Comment: How do you stop the [O/M1234] being encoded? I couldn't find a way with the classes I'm using

Comment: @TomSquires: I have updated the answer with additional details on how you could do this (I did verify through fiddler that it passes the string unescaped).

Comment: Oddly that gives the same error despite giving an output exactly the same as quoted in the documentation. Darvin's method did work though. (despite not looking like the documentation). THanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a complete answer, but you could look at using a socket instead of WebRequest and performing the HTTP request yourself. It seems that the multipart handler on your server is non-conformi g and expects the request to be the same as IE6 would make, so emulating that yourself would be the best approach.